# Error while receiving ArrayList<Class> in WebService of Spring sent from Android App

Tags: android, spring, web-services, retrofit

I want to send ArrayList class to Spring Web Service from Android App,
it is receiving JSON kind of data which should be cast automatically to ArrayList in web service but it is not fully doing that.

Code from android app

Some.class

```
public ServerResponse addSelectedProducts(ArrayList<TotalSelectedProduct> totalSelectedProducts) {
  

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES).create();

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("http://10.0.3.2:8082")
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .build();
    RetrofitService service = restAdapter.create(RetrofitService.class);
    try {
        ServerResponse serverResponse = service.addSelectedProducts(totalSelectedProducts);
        Log.i("imin:aProducts&i got",Boolean.toString(serverResponse.isAdded()));
        return serverResponse;
    } catch (RetrofitError error) {
        Log.e("***Error***",error.toString());
    }
    ServerResponse dr=new ServerResponse();
    dr.setAdded(false);
    return dr;
}
```

Interface code

```
@Headers({ "Content-Type: application/json" })
@POST("/VendorWebApplication/addSelectedProducts")
public ServerResponse addSelectedProducts(@Body ArrayList<TotalSelectedProduct> totalSelectedProducts);
```

Web Service Code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addSelectedProducts",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes="application/json")
    @ResponseBody 
    public ServerResponse addSelectedProducts(@RequestBody ArrayList<TotalSelectedProduct> totalSelectedProducts){
         System.out.println("imIn:"+"addSelectedProductsGotSelected"+totalSelectedProducts.toString());
        
        try{
         int i=1;
         while (i < totalSelectedProducts.size()){
                
             System.out.println("i:"+i);
                System.out.println("ProductId:"+String.valueOf(totalSelectedProducts.get(i).getProductId()));
                System.out.println("VendorId:"+totalSelectedProducts.get(i).getVendorId());
                i++; 
                }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("EEE"+e.toString());
        }
        
        
        return serverResponse;
        
        
    }
```

TotalSelectedProduct.class

```
public class TotalSelectedProduct {

@SerializedName("vendorId")
int vendorId;
@SerializedName("productId")
int productId;
@SerializedName("description")
String description;


public TotalSelectedProduct() {

}

public int getVendorId() {
    return vendorId;
}

public void setVendorId(int vendorId) {
    this.vendorId = vendorId;
}

public int getProductId() {
    return productId;
}

public void setProductId(int productId) {
    this.productId = productId;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

}

Now Console showing exception :

> imIn:addSelectedProductsGotSelected[{productId=2, vendorId=1}, {productId=3, vendorId=1}]
>
> EEEjava.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.arsenal.vendorappserver.model.TotalSelectedProduct

Here you can see `toString()` is working which is showing is JSON format but it is not performing action when we use that as `ArrayList<>`

Can any one tell Should add something to convert JSON to `ArrayList<Class>` ?

**After Edit:** also this is beans as convertor

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: You declared parameter a list but got a map.

Comment: If @ResponseBody ServerResponse  is what you are returning, doesn't look like an array or list . I would recommend to return a java.util.List and you can accept it as an array. I did the same using RestTemplate, and worked like a charm.